# Spark Reading .7z files

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hdfs, 7zip

I am trying to read the spark .7z files using scala or java. I dont find any appropriate methods or functionality.

For the zip file, i am able to read as the ZipInputStream class takes a Input stream, but for the 7Z files the class SevenZFile doesnt take any input stream.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/javadocs/api-1.16/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/sevenz/SevenZFile.html

Zip file code

```
spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles("fileName").flatMap{case (name: String, content: PortableDataStream) =>
        val zis = new ZipInputStream(content.open)
        Stream.continually(zis.getNextEntry)
              .takeWhile(_ != null)
              .flatMap { _ =>
                  val br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zis))
                  Stream.continually(br.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null)
              }}
```

I am trying similar code for the 7z files something like

```
spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles(""filename"").flatMap{case (name: String, content: PortableDataStream) =>
        val zis = new SevenZFile(content.open)
        Stream.continually(zis.getNextEntry)
              .takeWhile(_ != null)
              .flatMap { _ =>
                  val br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zis))
                  Stream.continually(br.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null)
              }}
```

But SevenZFile doesnt accept these formats.Looking for ideas.

If the file is in local filessytem following solution works, but my file is in hdfs

Local fileSystem Code

```
 public static void decompress(String in, File destination) throws IOException {
        SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(new File(in));
        SevenZArchiveEntry entry;
        while ((entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry()) != null){
            if (entry.isDirectory()){
                continue;
            }
            File curfile = new File(destination, entry.getName());
            File parent = curfile.getParentFile();
            if (!parent.exists()) {
                parent.mkdirs();
            }
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(curfile);
            byte[] content = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
            sevenZFile.read(content, 0, content.length);
            out.write(content);
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

After all these years of spark evolution there should be easy way to do it.

Comment: Can you please explain me if the files is stored in hdfs in the binary form as `example.7z`?

Comment: @silentsudo, yes the files are stored in hdfs

Comment: @silentsudo the files are stored in hdfs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the `java.io.File`-based approach, you could try the `SeekableByteChannel` method as shown in this [alternative constructor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/sevenz/SevenZFile.html#SevenZFile-java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel-char:A-).

You can use a [SeekableInMemoryByteChannel](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/utils/SeekableInMemoryByteChannel.html) to read a byte array. So as long as you can pick up the 7zip files from S3 or whatever and hand them off as byte arrays you should be alright.

With all of that said, Spark is really not well-suited for processing things like zip and 7zip files. I can tell you from personal experience I've seen it fail badly once the files are too large for Spark's executors to handle.

Something like Apache NiFi will work much better for expanding archives and processing them. FWIW, I'm currently handling a large data dump that has me frequently dealing with 50GB tarballs that have several million files in them, and NiFi handles them very gracefully.

Comment: How can we pass the PortableDataStream into the  SeekableInMemoryByteChannel.

Comment: Can you help me on passing  PortableDataStream into the SeekableInMemoryByteChannel

Comment: I don't know much about spark, so you're going to have to experiment with that on your own. That said, I strongly advise you to not use Spark with compressed archives. It's a really bad mismatch on tools and pretty much never works out.